# Mr. Who Am I? Please tell me

Tags: riddle, video-games

I have a brother who is taller than me. I have been a good guy and a bad guy. I was once known as Jumpman. I was in lots of video games.

Comment: This isn't really a riddle...

Comment: @Aidan Be careful about posting too many riddles too quickly. Take some time and try to contribute something that conveys a lot of thought and effort, and your rep will go up much faster.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's trivia, not a puzzle.

Comment: There's no significant difference between this and most of the other "what am I?" puzzles *except* that it's marginally easier.

Comment: @question_asker The other ones usually rely on wordplay or some other form of misdirection. This one does not.

Comment: @Deusovi yeah lemme restate: there are only four clues in this one; the third clue is (I assume) easily googlable, and the fourth narrows down the pool of entities to guess significantly. if the third clue was reworked (it wouldn't take much) and a different fourth clue was used, this one would be indistinguishable (in form, not content) from others we accept here.

Comment: This is a riddle, why is it closed as off-topic? So what if it's not good. Help center says nothing about riddles having to be good to be on-topic. Closing as off-topic needs to mean that it's off-topic or you're losing the meaning and point of having different close types. You can't just close a question when you feel like it. Yes it is trivia. Yes it is also a riddle. Ergo, should not be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> Mario

And your brother is

> Luigi